# AdSense Interstitial/Vignette ads in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adsense, next.js

I'm trying to implement page-level ads (interstitial/vignette) in a React SPA. It looks like Google's implementation only works via a hard page navigation, but the library I'm using (`nextjs`) makes heavy use of "soft" nav.

I've implemented it as they've described in their documentation

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount () {
    window[ "adsbygoogle" ] = window[ "adsbygoogle" ] || []

    try {
      window[ "adsbygoogle" ].push({
        "google_ad_client": `ca-pub-${ getAdsenseClientId() }`,
        "enable_page_level_ads": true
      })
    } catch (err) { log("adsbygoogle err", err) }
  }
  ...
}
```

I have a couple hard links on my page (`<a>`s), which, when using the IA debug (`#google_ia_debug`), show the interstitial, but all my internal links (using `nextjs`' builtin `Link` component) do nothing despite the debug util marking the links as valid for interstitials.

Is there a "trick" to getting this working with a SPA? Or am I SOL?

Comment: I don't know about google ads specifics but you can't use `window` without testing if you are rendering on the server or client. I have this convenient function that I use everywhere on my project to test on which side we are `export const isServer = (): boolean => (!process.browser ? true : false)`

Comment: @ClémentPrévost `componentDidMount` only runs client-side.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this @TylerSebastian ? I'm trying to trigger an interstitial banner on react router link tag.

Comment: You cannot trigger an interstitial banner programmatically with Google Adsense. And it is a policy: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2660562?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanipulating-how-ads-are-served